# Ошибка в связанном классе

Tags: python, ооп

Изучаю ООП, но в чём заключается ошибка так и не понял.

```
class Restaurant():
"""Типы ресторанов"""

    def __init__(self, name, type, list=0):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type


    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(f"{self.name} прекрасный ресторан!. Это {self.type} ресторан")
      
      
    def open_restaurant(self):
        print(f"{self.name} открыт")


class IceCreamStend(Restaurant):
    def __init__(self,name,type,list):
        self.list = list
        super().__init__(name,type,list)
        self.restaurant = Restaurant()
    
def listik(self):
    for obj in self.list:
        print (f"Ваш список:\n\t{obj}")
    
        
            
               
xs = IceCreamStend('BR','закусочная',['мароха','чёрная мароха','мароха пломбир'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странно, что у Вас вообще прилавок мороженного хранит в себе ресторан, а не наоборот.

Comment: Михаил, так нада

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно передать параметры в конструктор `Restaurant` на строчке:

```
self.restaurant = Restaurant()
```

Я предполагаю, что должно быть что-то типа этого:

```
self.restaurant = Restaurant(name, type, list)
```